# How to get the background color of an HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

How can I get the background color of any element, like a `<div>`, using JavaScript? I have tried:

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="myDivID" style="background-color: red">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <input type="button" value="click me" onclick="getColor();">
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getColor() {
    myDivObj = document.getElementById("myDivID")
    if (myDivObj) {
      console.log('myDivObj.bgColor: ' + myDivObj.bgColor); // shows: undefined
      console.log('myDivObj.backgroundcolor: ' + myDivObj.backgroundcolor); // shows: undefined
      //alert ( 'myDivObj.background-color: ' + myDivObj.background-color ); // this is not a valid property :)
      console.log('style:bgColor: ' + getStyle(myDivObj, 'bgColor')); //shows: undefined
      console.log('style:backgroundcolor: ' + getStyle(myDivObj, 'backgroundcolor')); // shows:undefined:
      console.log('style:background-color: ' + getStyle(myDivObj, 'background-color')); // shows: undefined
    } else {
      console.error('Error: When function "getColor();" was called, no element existed with an ID of "myDivId".');
    }
  }
  /* copied from `QuirksMode`  - http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html - */
  function getStyle(x, styleProp) {
    if (x.currentStyle)
      var y = x.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
      var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that the (currently) accepted answer will only work under a very restricted set of circumstances.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As with all css properties that contain hyphens, their corresponding names in JS is to remove the hyphen and make the following letter capital: `backgroundColor`

```
alert(myDiv.style.backgroundColor);
```

Comment: David will you please let me know why `getStyle` is used in `http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html`, when it was so easy to get the style property.

Comment: well the page you link to has some descriptions in itself as to what it's good for. for mozilla, for instance, it uses `getComputedStyle`, which is not so much what's specified in the stylesheet, but rather, what happens to be displayed, both as a result of HTML markup *and* CSS styling. For something as simple as this scenario, though, I don't see any really good reason to use that function.

Comment: The `style` property only contains styles assigned in a `style` attribute or set by scripting. Styles set in a `style` element or an external stylesheet won't be found there, at which point you need different techniques for different browsers (standard techniques for everything but IE, as usual) which ppk's `quirksmode` script will take care of.

Answer (score 125):

Get at number:

```
window.getComputedStyle( *Element* , null).getPropertyValue( *CSS* );
```

Example:

```
window.getComputedStyle( document.body ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color');  
window.getComputedStyle( document.body ,null).getPropertyValue('width');  
~ document.body.clientWidth
```

Comment: The second parameter is an optional property used to specify the pseudo element, so it can be safely omitted. See the documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Please be aware that this is a very expensive operation. Use with caution!

Comment: This won't work with pseudo-class, such as ":hover".

Answer (score 40):

Simple solution

```
myDivObj = document.getElementById("myDivID")
let myDivObjBgColor = window.getComputedStyle(myDivObj).backgroundColor;
```

Now the background color is stored in the new variable.

https://jsfiddle.net/7q1dpeo9/1/

Comment: As opposed to the accepted answer, this gives the color even if it is assigned through a class.

Answer (score 26):

**With jQuery:**

```
jQuery('#myDivID').css("background-color");
```

**With prototype:**

```
$('myDivID').getStyle('backgroundColor');
```

**With pure JS:**

```
document.getElementById("myDivID").style.backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 12):

It depends which style from the div you need. Is this a background style which was defined in `CSS` or background style which was added through `javascript(inline)` to the current node?

In case of `CSS` style, you should use computed style. Like you do in `getStyle()`.

With inline style you should use `node.style` reference: `x.style.backgroundColor`;

Also notice, that you pick the style by using camelCase/non hyphen reference, so not `background-color`, but `backgroundColor`;

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
var backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(myDiv, null).getPropertyValue("background-color") : myDiv.style.backgroundColor;
```

And, even better:

```
var getStyle = function(element, property) {
    return window.getComputedStyle ? window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(property) : element.style[property.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); })];
};
var backgroundColor = getStyle(myDiv, "background-color");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/css):

```
var color = $('#myDivID').css("background-color");
```

Comment: the div before the id selector is a little redundant

Comment: downloading and executing a 20kb library for retrieving the background color of a DIV is a little redundant ;)

Comment: well, if the only javascript used in the whole page is to get the background color, then it is redundant, but usually a page has much more things done in javascript, which makes using JQuery a little reasonable.

Comment: Those who want to avoid jQuery will find [this blog](http://acuriousanimal.com/blog/2012/07/09/look-mom-no-jquery-getting-all-css-properties-of-a-dom-element-in-pure-javascript/) useful. In short: you have to go into browser-specific details/features.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a canvas element over you control, even without display it, to get the color at a specific position in you controls, if it has many colors.

```html
<head>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body><div style="border:gray solid 2px;height:575px;width:700px;position:absolute;top:75px;right:15px;background:black;color:white;font-Family:Century SchoolBook;font-Size:18px;padding-Top:20px;" id="container101"><div id="header" style="text-Align:center">ColorPicker</div> 
    <div id="div101" style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:100px;width:500px;height:500px;"></div> 
    <canvas height="500" width="500" style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:100px;display:none;" id="canva"></canvas>

</div>

<script>
    function create(r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2){dv101 = 
    document.querySelector("#div101");dv101.style.background = "linear-gradient(90deg, rgb("+r1+", "+g1+", "+b1+"), rgb("+r2+", "+g2+", "+b2+"))";
    var can = document.querySelector("#canva");
    var context = can.getContext("2d");
    context.rect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    var grd = context.createLinearGradient(0,0,can.width,0);
    grd.addColorStop(0, "rgb("+r1+", "+g1+", "+b1+")");
    grd.addColorStop(1, "rgb("+r2+", "+g2+", "+b2+")");
    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fillRect(0,0,500,500);

    dv101.onmousemove = (event) => {
        var posx = event.clientX-dv101.offsetLeft- 
        document.querySelector("#container101").offsetLeft;
        var posy = event.clientY-dv101.offsetTop- 
        document.querySelector("#container101").offsetTop;
        console.log(posx,posy);
        var data = context.getImageData(posx,posy,1,1);
        couleur = "rgb("+data.data[0]+","+data.data[1]+","+data.data[2]+")";
        document.body.style.background=couleur;
    } return couleur;
};create(255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255);
var arr = new Array();
function inp(x,y){
    var input1 = document.createElement('input');
    var cont = document.querySelector("#container101");
    cont.appendChild(input1);
    arr.push(input1);
    input1.type = "text";
    input1.style = "outline:none;position:absolute;top:"+y+"px;left:"+x+"px;height:30px;width:60px;background:white;color:black;";
    input1.value = 0;
    input1.onkeydown = (event) => {

        switch(event.keyCode){

        case 38:
            input1.value++;
            create(arr[0].value, arr[1].value, arr[2].value, arr[3].value, arr[4].value,arr[5].value);
            break;

        case 40:
            input1.value--;
            create(arr[0].value, arr[1].value, arr[2].value, arr[3].value, arr[4].value,arr[5].value);
            break;
        };
    }
};inp(5,60);inp(5,110);inp(5,160);inp(610,60);inp(610,110);inp(610,160);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is a working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/cdgpts9n/

Comment: Please provide formatted code. Also, the question is about getting the background color of an HTML element, but I think your answer is about selecting a color from a canvas with the mouse - that's something else entirely, isn't it?