# Return background color of clicked element js

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to send the background color of an element to a function using javascript for example:

```
<td style="background-color:#ff0000" onClick="getColor()"></td>
```

Could anyone please give me a pointer as to what I have to do in the getColor() function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the background color of an element using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Comment: @BarryKaye This is not a duplicate coz that article applies to a single element, I want to use the same function in the onclick method for multiple elements getting their background colors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this to:

```
<td style="background-color:#ff0000" onClick="getColor(this)"></td>
```

And this would be the javasctipt:

```
getColor(elem){
    alert(elem.style.backgroundColor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, except it prints rgb(x,x,x). Can i get a hex value instead? like: #ff0000

Answer (score 2):

If jQuery is ok:

```
<td style="background-color:#ff0000" onClick="getColor(this)"></td>
<script>
function getColor(element) {
    var bgColor = $(element).css('background-color');
    // ... do something with bgColor here...
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use javascript, do you know how to do the same in js?

Comment: sans481 and Christian Kuetbach have answered your question with solutions in plain javascript.

Comment: Thanx I saw but it prints a value like: rgb(x,x,x). Can I get a hex value instead? like: #ff0000

Answer (score 1):

Modify the call to send the object as param. Like this-

```
<td style="background-color:#ff0000" onClick="getColor(this)"></td>
```

And the function would be-

```
function getColor(obj){
 var bgColor = obj.style.backgroundColor;
 alert(var);
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped, although it prints a value like rgb(x,x,x). Can I somehow get a hex value from that eg. #ff0000?

Comment: which browser you use? For me in IE, it returns #ff0000.

Comment: I use chrome, When i create _alert(obj.style.backgroundColor)_ It shows an alertbox stating rgb(x,x,x). I tested it in IE and you're right, I'll try parsing the object and re-assigning the received value to an elements color