# How to pass the color of this element to javascript without using inline stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720620/return-background-color-of-clicked-element-js) in that I need to pass the background color that an element has to a javascript function. The difference is that I want the color to be defined outside the element itself, in a stylesheet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        button.red_button {
          background: red;
          cursor: pointer;
          border: none;
          width: 48px;
          height: 48px;
        }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <button class="red_button" onclick="javascript:changeColor(this)"></button>

        <p id="change_me">Click on the red box to change this text to red!</p>

        <script>
            function changeColor(button) {
                document.getElementById("change_me").style.color = button.style.background;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine when the background color is defined inline, but can't seem to find it when it's declared externally.

Comment: [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get the all the styles applied on the button. Then apply it to the text

```
 function changeColor(button) {
   var style = window.getComputedStyle(button);
   document.getElementById("change_me").style.color = style['background-color'];
 }
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rgxvy5uy/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As @**nnnnnn** mentioned you can use `getComputedStyle()` to get the CSS of your element, simply `.style` only gets the inline `style` attribute of the element:

```
function changeColor(button) {
    document.getElementById("change_me").style.color = getComputedStyle(button)['background-color'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        button.red_button {
          background: red;
          cursor: pointer;
          border: none;
          width: 48px;
          height: 48px;
        }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <button class="red_button" onclick="changeColor('#ff0000');"></button>

        <p id="change_me">Click on the red box to change this text to red!</p>

        <script>
            function changeColor(color) {
                document.getElementById("change_me").style.color = color;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

what I did is I changed a bit of the script so that you set the color on the function, and it colors the place automatically

Comment: I wanted to use a stylesheet to hold the color, not the element itself. That was the whole point of not simply doing `style="background: red"`