# Get current applied style with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was looking at this post
[How to get the background color of an element using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-javascript)

which confirmed that if you do

```
div.style.color
```

you will get returned the color applied to the div.

However this only seems to return a result if the style is applied inline on the element?

How do you return the style applied to the element when the style is applied through a style sheet (or in  tags) rather than directly inline?

See example below.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundColor);
console.log(document.getElementById('content').style.color);
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="color:red;"></div>
```

console.log(document.getElementById('content').style.backgroundColor);

returns nothing

console.log(document.getElementById('content').style.color);

returns red

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use `getComputedStyle()` to get the styles assigned through the stylesheet.

```js
console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('content')).backgroundColor);
console.log(document.getElementById('content').style.color);
```

```css
#content {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" style="color:red;"></div>
```