# Why does my function give me "this is not red"?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to see if a cell has a red background, when I put test in the inputbox 
 and click the button, I receive the message "this is not red". Could someone please 
 explain to me how I could make it say "this is red"?

```js
var colors = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)"];

function testfunction() {
  var location = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  if (document.getElementById(location).style.backgroundColor == colors[0]) {
    alert("This is red");
  } else {
    alert("This is not red");
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test" class="red"> a1 </td>
    <td id="test2"> b1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="test3"> a2 </td>
    <td id="test4" class="red"> b2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="userinput" type="text">

<button id="button" onclick="testfunction()"> Button </button>
```

Comment: because `document.getElementById(location).style.backgroundColor` is not equal to `colors[0]`. Log the background color to debug

Comment: what's this? `id=t est` why the space in each `id`? **id's** do not allow spaces.

Comment: `Element.style` gives you the inline-styles defined for this Element. But you set the `background-color` in the css. Check out [getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: @Roy this was an error introduced by the first editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get current applied style with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28203363/get-current-applied-style-with-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `node.style` wont give you computed styles. You have to use [window.getComputedStyle(element)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to check computed styles .

So following code should work

```
var colors = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)"];

function testfunction() {
  var location = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  if (getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(location)).backgroundColor == colors[0]) {
    alert("This is red");
  } else {
    alert("This is not red");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the actual style used at runtime. The `style` property of the element will only give you information on the inline style of the element.

```js
var colors = ["rgb(255, 0, 0)"];

function testfunction() {
  var location = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
  var style = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(location));

  if (style.backgroundColor == colors[0]) {
    alert("This is red");
  } else {
    alert("This is not red");
  }
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="test" class="red"> a1 </td>
    <td id="test2"> b1 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="test3"> a2 </td>
    <td id="test4" class="red"> b2 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="userinput" type="text">

<button id="button" onclick="testfunction()"> Button </button>
```