# How do I get the color attribute of the returned div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an HTML div like below

```
<div class="some-class">
        <div class="color-rect"></div>
        <div class="color-rect"></div>
        <div class="color-rect"></div>
</div>
```

And a corresponding CSS for the same as below

```
.color-rect {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

Now I want to fetch the color of the div on click (which is red by default), with the following code,

```
$(".color-rect").click(function(e){
        e.target.attr("background-color");
    });
```

This doesn't work. After I put in the debugger I see that e.target just gives me the div with none of the CSS attributes. How do I get the color of the clicked div?

Comment: $(this).attr("background-color"); returns undefined

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the background color of an element using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery object $(this) to select the element you click and then use jquery method .css() to get any property that you need.

```
$(".color-rect").click(function(e){
    //e.target.attr("background-color");
    console.log($(this).css("background-color"));
});
```

Here is a complete fiddle for demonstration. [JS Fiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/3b2jk247/)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
$(this).css("background-color");
```

or

```
$(e.target).css("background-color");
```

Comment: OP means CSS property.

Answer (score 1):

`e.target` gives you Html Element and `$(e.target)` gives you jquery accessor then you can query `background-color` attribute by `css`

```js
$(".color-rect").click(function(e){
        console.log($(e.target).css('background-color'));
  
    });
```

```css
.color-rect {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
        <div class="color-rect"></div>
        <div class="color-rect"></div>
        <div class="color-rect"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(".color-rect").click(function(e){
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lbzw3ye2/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using jQuery you can use `.css` like this:

```
console.log($(this).css('backgroundColor'));
```

This gives you the rgb-value of the color.

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0tyLa5xt/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this.

**Javascript**

```
var cs = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e.target,null);
alert(cs.getPropertyValue('background-color'));
```

**jQuery**

```
alert($(this).css('background-color'));
```

See the demo below.

```js
$(".color-rect").click(function(e){
    var cs = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e.target,null);
    alert(cs.getPropertyValue('background-color'));
    alert($(this).css('background-color'));
});
```

```css
.color-rect {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-class">
    <div class="color-rect"></div>
    <div class="color-rect"></div>
    <div class="color-rect"></div>
</div>
```