# How to get an html element's color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

css:

```
p {
  color: red;
}
```

html:

```
<p id='h1'>asd</p>


<script>
var h1 = document.getElementById('h1');
</script>
```

why do I get an empty string when I type "h1.style.color" in the console?

Comment: Because you haven't set the color property of the style object. Notice, that inline styles are totally separated from cascaded stylesheets. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: This is what you are after: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991851/3233388

Comment: It's empty because you are trying to retrieve this info from CSS, the style.color reads the inline css directive.

You can add inline style <p id='h1' style="color:red;">asd</p>

Comment: yes, but I want to set the CSS, not the inline css, is there an alternative to style.color?
edit: so getComputedStyle, ty Adelin

Comment: You can use JQuery if you want to access styles from within CSS.