# Why is background color not changing when using style.backgroundColor?

Tags: javascript, html

What I am trying to do is to save the current tab background color in a var, and later use that var to change the body color. But why is it not working?

```js
const tabName = 'someId';
var thisTabColor = document.getElementById(tabName).style.backgroundColor;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisTabColor;
```

```css
#someId {
  background-color: #cccccc; /* or whatever */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="someId">Some text here</div>
</body>
```

In the above example, the body's background doesn't change to `#cccccc`, the `div`'s color.

Comment: `thisTabColor` return right value?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: what is your tabName value and does it exist in the DOM?

Comment: tabName is passed as the function argument function openTab(evt, tabName)

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991851) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var tabName = 'container';
var tabElement = document.getElementById(tabName);
var computedStyles = window.getComputedStyle(tabElement);
var thisTabColor = computedStyles.getPropertyValue('background-color');
document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisTabColor;
```

```css
#container {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `#`

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisTabColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

why you concatenate with "#"?
the 1st instruction will return the color value
you should remove the #

Comment: Because I read somewhere else that I should concatenate the # because is hex color