# How to change backgorundColor element onclick in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript. I wanna change the color of menu button when I click on it and change the color back when I click it second time. I wrote a simple code in JS, but it does nothing.

```js
document.getElementById("menuBtn div").onclick = changeColor;

function changeColor() {
  if (changeColor.style.backgroundColor === "#EF6A6A") {
    changeColor.style.backgroundColor = "#fff"
  } else {
    changeColor.style.backgroundColor = '#EF6A6A'
  }
}

changeColor()
```

```css
#menuBtn {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 65px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menuBtn div {
  width: 38px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #EF6A6A;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 2100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBtn">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong `menuBtn div`.  Are you wanting to change the colour of the children or the parent?

Comment: `changeColor`,a function, has no `style` property

Comment: There are many error in code, JS can't search element with `menuBtn div"`. This is not an id. It should be `menuBtn`

Comment: @Pete The selector is wrong in either case because OP uses `.getElementById()` and not `.querySelector()`/`.querySelectorAll()`

Comment: @Andreas I know, that's why I said the selector is wrong - but depending on what they are trying to do will change the type of answer given - one requires looping through the children and changing the way they get the elements, the other you can just change the selector and fix the function

Comment: A lost of mistakes here. i count 4... `changeColor.style` -- `changeColor` here is also wrong, look at https://javascript.info/event-delegation Also when checking background color you re not getting HEX value, you wil get RGB https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-html-element So your if statement is also wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to create a new css class and toggle with button click. Below would change the `backgroundColor` of the `menuBtn`.

```js
const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn");

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

function changeColor() {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle("bgColorOrange");
}
```

```css
#menuBtn {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 65px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menuBtn div {
  width: 38px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #EF6A6A;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 2100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.bgColorOrange {
  background-color: #EF6A6A;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBtn">
  <div class="line1"></div>
  <div class="line2"></div>
  <div class="line3"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to add background color white of lines when `menuBtn` background color is `#EF6A6A`. You can again create a new class and toggle on click of a button.

```js
const menuBtn = document.getElementById("menuBtn");
const lines = document.querySelectorAll(".line");

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", changeColor);

function changeColor() {
  menuBtn.classList.toggle("bgColorOrange");
  lines.forEach(line => line.classList.toggle("bgColorWhite"));
}
```

```css
#menuBtn {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 65px;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#menuBtn div {
  width: 38px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #EF6A6A;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 2100px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.bgColorOrange{
  background-color: #EF6A6A;
}

.bgColorWhite{
  background: white !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuBtn">
  <div class="line1 line"></div>
  <div class="line2 line"></div>
  <div class="line3 line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are referencing your function `changeColor`, which doesn't have a property `style.backgroundColor`. You'll want to make sure you're referencing your DOM element:

```
const element = document.getElementById("menuBtn")
element.onclick = changeColor;

function changeColor() {
    if (element.style.backgroundColor === rgb(0,0,0)) {
        element.style.backgroundColor = rgb(3,2,1)
    } else {
        element.style.backgroundColor = rgb(0,0,0)
    }
}
```

I've also fixed your selector tag.

Comment: Also when checking background color you re not getting HEX value, you wil get RGB