# How to change the color of a div from an exiting color on already?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically if you get what I am doing, I want it to be such that when I click the next button the color of one goes to three and three goes to two and two goes to one.
I have been trying to make it fetch the color of two but without success

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<Head>
    <style>
        div {
            height: 50px;
        }
        
        #one {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f00;
        }
        
        #two {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #0f0;
            float: left;
        }
        
        #three {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #00f;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function oneToTwo() {
            document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById("two").style.backgroundColor;
        }
    </script>
</Head>

<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Back" title="The back button">
    <input type="button" value="Next" title="The next button" onclick="oneToTwo()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `element.style.property` almost always results in a blank string (`""`). You can get the CSS of an element with `document.styleSheets`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952667/find-all-css-rules-that-apply-to-an-element

Comment: Defining a style in a stylesheet does not update the style of an element. You can use conputedStyle to get the styles that the system has worked out.

Comment: There's further discusion of this seemingly strange behaviour here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-html-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A style that is inherited from a class is not accessible via an individual style property. You can however use `getComputedStyle`, although I would actually just store those colors in variables. But for the purpose of showing what `getComputedStyle` can do, here is an adapted script:

```js
let areas = document.querySelectorAll(".area");

function rotate(dir=1) {
    // Fetch colors
    let colors = Array.from(areas, area => getComputedStyle(area).backgroundColor);
    // Rotate them
    if (dir == 1) colors.push(colors.shift());
    else colors.unshift(colors.pop());
    // Assign them back
    areas.forEach(area => area.style.backgroundColor = colors.shift());
}
```

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
}

#one {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f00;
}

#two {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #0f0;
    float: left;
}

#three {
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #00f;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="one" class="area"></div>
<div id="two" class="area"></div>
<div id="three" class="area"></div>
<input type="button" value="Back" title="The back button" onclick="rotate(-1)">
<input type="button" value="Next" title="The next button" onclick="rotate(1)">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this I can see that you also did the back button for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window.getComputedStyle() to acces all the CSS properties of an element. Here you can use the

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("two")).backgroundColor;
```

to access the background color of your second div element.

Further documentation on getComputedStyle() can be accesed here:

[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<Head>
    <style>
        div {
            height: 50px;
        }
        
        #one {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f00;
        }
        
        #two {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #0f0;
            float: left;
        }
        
        #three {
            width: 50%;
            background-color: #00f;
            float: right;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function oneToTwo() {
            document.getElementById("one").style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("two")).backgroundColor;

        }
    </script>
</Head>

<body>
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
    <input type="button" value="Back" title="The back button">
    <input type="button" value="Next" title="The next button" onclick="oneToTwo()">
</body>

</html>
```